# wrong work of slide out top animation android

Tags: android

I have animation, that moves current activity to the top and next activity appears under outgoing activity. Animation works fine, but **problem** is obtained app makes the animation in the same(next) activity(app firstly starts next activity then starts my animation)
I start activity and animation by this way:

```
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_top,R.anim.noanimate);
```

Code of slide_out_top.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" 
    android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Code of noanimate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

I tried to switch places between starting activity and animation , but it didn't work

Comment: overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim) pass anim properly first param for enter which was call on create the exit on destroy

Comment: @Survivor, you are right, my mistake, but could you give some advice, now,  slide_out_top I m using as exitAnim, and other slide_in_bottom I m using as enterAnim, problem is I need next activity is stayed without animation, if I m using noanimation as the enterAnim, I cant see exitAnim

Comment: you have to override onDestroy() and put again this overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim) thats it

Comment: @Survivor, great! thanks!